# How to change color of pie slice when mouse hover event take place

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a pie chart in `matplotlib`. I want to achieve [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztJkb/4/) result in python **i.e. whenever the mouse is hovered on any slice its color is changed**.I have searched a lot and came up with the use of `bind` method but that was not effective though and therefore was not able to come up with the positive result. I will have no problem if this can be done through any other library(say `tkinter`, `plotly`,etc but I need to come up with the solution with `matplotlib` so I would appreciate that more).Please have a look through my question and any suggestion is warmly welcomed...
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
sizes = [10, 35, 50, 5]
explode = (0, 0, 0.1, 0)  # only "explode" the 3rd slice (i.e. 'C')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

Regards...

Comment: What about the `figure_enter_event`?

Comment: Can you provide some samples Sir?

Comment: The documentation has some examples: https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#mouse-enter-and-leave

Comment: I will surely look at it Sir!!!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a [matplotlib event handler](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) for a `motion_notify_event`. 
This can be connected to a function which checks if the mouse is inside one of the pie chart's wedges. This is done via [`contains_point`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.contains_point). In that case colorize the wedge differently, else set its color to its original color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
sizes = [10, 35, 50, 5]
explode = (0, 0, 0.1, 0)  # only "explode" the 3rd slice (i.e. 'C')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
wedges, _, __ = ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

ocols= [w.get_facecolor() for w in wedges]
ncols= ["gold", "indigo", "purple", "salmon"]

def update(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax1:
        for i, w in enumerate(wedges):
            if w.contains_point([event.x, event.y]):
                w.set_facecolor(ncols[i])
            else:
                w.set_facecolor(ocols[i])
        fig1.canvas.draw_idle()


fig1.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: as usual, your answer is very informative. I was looking for a way to identify the wedge over which the mouse was. I did not know about `contains_point()`, glad to have learnt something new.

Comment: @DizietAsahi I just happen to have answered [a question about `contains_point`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986805/4124317) the other day, so I had it fresh in my mind. ;-) However, ideally I would have liked to use [`contains(event)`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.contains), which for some reason did not work as expected (it always returns True if mouse is inside the axes, not only the wedge in question).

Comment: You are a miracle worker Sir!!!Thank you very much. I was stuck in it for more than 21 hrs...Sir I would like to know just one thing (although very silly and apologise for it) Sir if we want to show different colors for different slices on mouse hover we need to create multiple events or there can be some efficient option for it?

Comment: I updated the answer such that each wedge has a different "hover-color". You would just need to have a list of as many colors as you have wedges.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you are looking for is [the documentation on Event handling in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). In particular, the `motion_notify_event` will be fired every time the mouse moves. However, I can't think of an easy way to identify which wedge the mouse is over right now.

If clicking is acceptable, then the problem is much easier:

```
labels = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
sizes = [10, 35, 50, 5]
explode = (0, 0, 0.1, 0)  # only "explode" the 3rd slice (i.e. 'C')
click_color = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
patches, texts, autotexts = ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)

# store original color inside patch object
# THIS IS VERY HACKY.
# We use the Artist's 'gid' which seems to be unused as far as I can tell
# to be able to recall the original color
for p in patches:
    p.set_gid(p.get_facecolor())
    # enable picking
    p.set_picker(True)

ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.


def on_pick(event):
    #restore all facescolor to erase previous changes
    for p in patches:
        p.set_facecolor(p.get_gid())
    a = event.artist
    # print('on pick:', a, a.get_gid())
    a.set_facecolor(click_color)
    plt.draw()

fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!!!But I figured out this solution. I wanted that when mouse hover takes place then the changes occur not on click event!!!!But thanks again for giving your precious time